# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when upload POJOs models in Guvnor

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, drools-guvnor

I implement a Decision Engine using **Guvnor**, when I try to upload a **Model** using .jar file with the option "New->Upload a POJOs models" later click in "File->Save" and Guvnor throw a exception: **Can´t validate the packet configuration**. In the log, guvnor write:

```
10:37:32,592 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/drools-guvnor]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract org.drools.ide.common.client.modeldriven.SuggestionCompletionEngine org.drools.guvnor.client.rpc.SuggestionCompletionEngineService.loadSuggestionCompletionEngine(java.lang.String) throws com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException
  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385) [gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar:]
  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588) [gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar:]
  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208) [gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar:]
  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248) [gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar:]
  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar:]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.1.Final.jar:3.1.1.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.1.Final.jar:3.1.1.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  at org.drools.rule.MapBackedClassLoader.loadClass(MapBackedClassLoader.java:108) [drools-core-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  at org.drools.base.ClassTypeResolver.resolveType(ClassTypeResolver.java:155) [drools-core-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.ide.common.server.rules.SuggestionCompletionLoader.loadClass(SuggestionCompletionLoader.java:647) [droolsjbpm-ide-common-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.ide.common.server.rules.SuggestionCompletionLoader.addFactType(SuggestionCompletionLoader.java:606) [droolsjbpm-ide-common-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.ide.common.server.rules.SuggestionCompletionLoader.populateModelInfo(SuggestionCompletionLoader.java:320) [droolsjbpm-ide-common-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.ide.common.server.rules.SuggestionCompletionLoader.populateEngineBuilder(SuggestionCompletionLoader.java:224) [droolsjbpm-ide-common-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.ide.common.server.rules.SuggestionCompletionLoader.processPackageHeader(SuggestionCompletionLoader.java:218) [droolsjbpm-ide-common-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.ide.common.server.rules.SuggestionCompletionLoader.getSuggestionEngine(SuggestionCompletionLoader.java:186) [droolsjbpm-ide-common-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.guvnor.server.util.BRMSSuggestionCompletionLoader.getSuggestionEngine(BRMSSuggestionCompletionLoader.java:63) [classes:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.guvnor.server.util.BRMSSuggestionCompletionLoader.getSuggestionEngine(BRMSSuggestionCompletionLoader.java:70) [classes:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.guvnor.server.SuggestionCompletionEngineLoaderInitializer.loadFor(SuggestionCompletionEngineLoaderInitializer.java:42) [classes:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.guvnor.server.SuggestionCompletionEngineServiceImplementation.loadSuggestionCompletionEngine(SuggestionCompletionEngineServiceImplementation.java:48) [classes:5.5.0.Final]
  at org.drools.guvnor.server.SuggestionCompletionEngineServiceServlet.loadSuggestionCompletionEngine(SuggestionCompletionEngineServiceServlet.java:37) [classes:5.5.0.Final]
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569) [gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar:]
  ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException from [Module "deployment.drools-guvnor.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  at org.drools.rule.MapBackedClassLoader.loadClass(MapBackedClassLoader.java:108) [drools-core-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
  ... 47 more
```

When I push in "Validate configuration" I get this error: **Unable to find the class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException which is required by: *.deceng.utility.CDBConnection. You may need to add more classes to the model**. But I add this library en mi eclipse project

[image: Eclipse project]

And how you can see in the .jar classpath the sqljdbc4.jar are included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
       <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
       <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
       <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Model"/>
       <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jmflores/DECENG-TEST/ExtLib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
       <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/jmflores/DECENG-TEST/ExtLib/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I tried all but I don´t know that can I do.

Thanks and Regards.

Edit:

I try use Deployment Assembly but not work.

[image]

I add sqljdbc4.jar with deployment, later export project like .jar and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added that jar to your Eclipse Deployment Assembly? 
If not then please add the jar file to your Eclipse deployment assembly.

1. Right click your project.
2. Go to properties Select "Deployment Assembly"
3. On right pane, select "Add" and select your jar file.

Please follow [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/javaee.php).

Comment: I use Eclipse Indigo and this option not appear. I use new eclipse version and tell you what happened. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I use Deployment Assembly but not work. Edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggetion. Kindly see if the project facets under the project properties windows contains web module selected. If that is not selected the Deployment Assembly would not appear.

Once you select it you may require to do the necessary configuration for the project like selecting the deployment description and adding required dependencies and sources to it.

Hope this helps!

thanks
-vivek

Comment: A lot of thanks for suggestion. I had configure the project and now appear.

Comment: Can you Kindly let us know how the problem was solved and what was the  actual issue with the configuration

Comment: How I did to Deployment Assembly appear in project properties? Because my problem (Unable to find the class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException) never was solved.